# How to insert another table data into another table laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a two tables:

**qr_details table:**

```
id     product_id    qrcode_id     created_at           updated_at
1      1             12            2017-10-09 15:36:15  2017-10-09 15:36:15
2      3             13            2017-10-09 15:36:15  2017-10-09 15:36:15
```

**winners table:**

```
id     product_id    qrcode_id     winner_name  win_number  created_at           updated_at
1      1             12            hello        5           2017-10-09 15:36:15  2017-10-09 15:36:15
2      3             13            world        6           2017-10-09 15:36:15  2017-10-09 15:36:15
```

Now i want to get `qr_details` table `product_id` & `qrcode_id` into `winners` table. How can i do that with query in Laravel? I have made a SQL Fiddle **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbe9ef).** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just get details of `qr_details` table using simple get query and then use it to insert!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
$query = \DB::connection()->getPdo()->query("select * from qr_details");
$data = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

\DB::table('winners')->insert($data);
```

it will take a little time and just two queries

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question but you can try this:

```
$datas = DB::table('qr_details ')->get();

foreach($datas as $data){
    DB::table('winners')->insert(['qrcode_id' => $data->qrcode_id, 'product_id'=>$data->product_id, ...bunch other inserts])
}
```

Comment: if anyone insert data winner table then i want to get `qr_details` table `product_id` & `qrcode_id` into `winners` table. Your answer through s an error `Undefined property: stdClass::$product_id`

Answer (score 1):

i know this late but someone looking for solution you can use `chunk` laravel function. your tables have a large number of records, consider using a batch processing approach to avoid memory issues.

```
Table1::chunk(200, function ($table1Data) {
    foreach ($table1Data as $record) {
        // Create and save records in table2
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to add new records to the `winners` table then you could use `Eloquent` models and `insert` method to add multiple record in a single query.

```
$qcodes = Qrcode::all()->map(function(Qrcode $qrcode) {
    return [
        'id' => $qrcode->id,
        'product_id' => $qrcode->product_id,
        'qrcode_id' => $qrcode->qrcode_id,
        'winner_name' => 'some name',
        'win_number' => 5
    ];
});

Winner::insert($qcodes);
```

However, guessing from what you said, that's probably not what you're after - as you want only `product_id` and `qrcode_id` to be added - in other words to update existing records.

If that's the case, and if your `id` column matches in both of the tables then you could do something similar to:

```
$qcodes = Qrcode::all();

$qcodes->each(function(Qrcode $qrcode) {
    Winner::where('id', $qrcode->id)->update([
        'product_id' => $qrcode->product_id,
        'qrcode_id' => $qrcode->qrcode_id
    ]);
});
```

This is again assuming you are using `Eloquent` models - otherwise you'd have to do it using `Query Builder`:

```
$qcodes= DB::table('qr_details')->get();

$qcodes->each(function(Qrcode $qrcode) {
    DB::table('winners')
        ->where('id', $qrcode->id)
        ->update([
            'product_id' => $qrcode->product_id,
            'qrcode_id' => $qrcode->qrcode_id
        ]);
});
```

Make sure you update table / model names accordingly.

Now, one issue with your sql structure is that your `winners` table `product_id` and `qrcode_id` is `NOT NULL` so it has to have some data there when record is first created. If you were to update these records, I would suggest to change these two columns to `NULL` so that initially they don't require any data.